# Lazy fetch subclass columns (Java/Hibernate)

Tags: java, hibernate, inheritance, jpql

Suppose two JPA entities exist using Hibernate joined-table inheritance with a discriminate column:

Superclass: Shape

Subclass: Cycle

Running the JPQL `select s from Shape s where s.id=?1` this error returns:

```
Error: org.hibernate.WrongClassException: Object [id=61] was not of the specified subclass [model.Shape] : Discriminator: Cycle
```

This occurs because hibernate eagerly tries to fetch the Cycle information as well, but for some architectural reason, the Cycle class is not present in the classpath.

Question: is there a way to disable the secondary join query that hibernate executes automatically to join the subclass columns? Say something like this:

```
@Entity
@Inheritance(strategy = InheritanceType.JOINED) //Q: something here like 'fetch = FetchType.LAZY'
@DiscriminatorColumn(name = "DTYPE", discriminatorType = DiscriminatorType.STRING)
public class Shape {}
```

I resolved this by using projection (return the columns I really need) but I'm forced to execute additional queries for the joined columns, **unable to join fetch** tables for improved performance.

Comment: *but for some architectural reason, the Cycle class is not present in the classpath*. I am confused.

Comment: JPA is split into jars. A common jar with the supertype and a subdomain jar. Each war includes two jars (common+subdomain). Now, there is the need for a common dashboard app (common JPA only).